# Gridview in Corona Not scrolling

Tags: gridview, coronasdk

I am showing images in GridView in Corona but i don't know why GridView is not scrolling. Please guys help me how to do it ? my main.lua file code and screenshot is shown below

```
display.setStatusBar( display.DefaultStatusBar )
local widget = require( "widget" )
local gridView = require("gridView")
local photoArray ={"assets/pic1.png","assets/pic1.png","assets/pic2.png","assets/pic3.png","assets/pic4.png","assets/pic5.png","assets/pic5.png"}
local photoTextArray = {"pic7","pic1","pic2","pic3","pic4","pic5  Long Text Test","pic6"}
    gridView:new(25, 50, photoArray, photoTextArray, 2, 10, 20,150, 150, gridListener)
local function gridListener(index)
    print("You select item "..index)
end
```

[image]

I have used this link for doing this https://github.com/worldstar/GridView-for-Corona-SDK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, i have used scrollView widget in Corona to display images like in Gridview here is my code.

```
    display.setStatusBar( display.DefaultStatusBar )
    local widget = require( "widget" )

    local scrollView = widget.newScrollView
    {
        --left = 0,
        --top = 0,
        --width = display.contentWidth,
        --height = display.contentHeight,
        id = "onBottom",
        horizontalScrollDisabled = false,
        verticalScrollDisabled = false,
        listener = scrollListener,
    }

local centerX_Row1 = 110
local centerX_Row2 = 110
local shows        = {}
local length       = 5;

function displayShow( event )
    print( "Touch event began on: "..tostring(event.target[2].text))
![enter image description here][1]end 

for k = 1,length,1 do
    shows[k] = {}
    shows[k].image_name = "assets/pic8.png"
    shows[k].showname   = "show "..k
end

for k = 1,#shows,2 do
    --Row 1
    local group = display.newGroup();
    --local image       = display.newImage( shows[k].image_name )
    local image       = display.newImageRect(shows[k].image_name,175,125)
    local text        = display.newText(shows[k].showname,-40, -60, native.systemFontBold, 24 )
    group:insert(image)
    group:insert(text)
    group.x = centerX_Row1
    group.y = 100
    centerX_Row1 = centerX_Row1 + 190
    group:addEventListener( "tap", displayShow)
    scrollView:insert( group )

    if(k+1 <= #shows) then
        --Row 2
        local group   = display.newGroup();
        --local image       = display.newImage( shows[k+1].image_name )
        local image       = display.newImageRect(shows[k].image_name,175,125)
        local text        = display.newText(shows[k+1].showname, -40, -60, native.systemFontBold, 24 )
        group:insert(image)
        group:insert(text)
        group:addEventListener( "tap", displayShow)
        group.x = centerX_Row2
        group.y = 240
        centerX_Row2 = centerX_Row2 + 190

        scrollView:insert( group )
    end
end
```

[image: This is result of the given code]

Comment: Just a stab at the wind but based on the code you've shown you didn't set the scrollwidth and scrollheight. You need to set these two since they are both required. This determines the size of your scrollview. When I first used scrollview, I had the same problem. I just set the width and height and it worked. Here's the documentation for the scrollview: http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/widget/newScrollView.html

Comment: Well, good luck on your project. Hope I helped. :) Keep coding!